# Feed page size is too small on 7 Plus

Tags: bug, ios-app

I've noticed that every time I open the Stack Exchange app I'm greeted to a feed that only fills half the page. Specifically, I only see about 4 items in my feed.

Attempting to scroll triggers a loader and only loads in another 4 or so items. It makes the experience absolutely awful.

Anyone else seeing this?

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C89)

The screen in question (I will update when I can reproduce again). But it seems that when using the App after a long period of time without use, half the page will be empty and I have to trigger a scroll action repetitively as it seems to only load 4 items at a time

> [image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and add it? I think that will make your post better to understand.

Comment: totally @PatrickHofman its just difficult to get the app back into this state again. Happens after a long period of time

Comment: Is it possible this is related to network issues?

Comment: @PatrickHofman not really, it loads data fine. I just think it's maybe a bug on how it does prefetching if contentSize is less than pageSize on the tableView/collectionView